# Remove Duplicate Rows From Datagridview Without A New Button

Tags: c#, datagridview, duplicates, row

I have a datagridview, it has two columns and I get it's values from my SQL-Server table (3 columns). Can it possible to remove duplicate rows without using a new button?

It's my code:

```
                    foreach (DataRow r in d.Rows)
                    {
                        dgw.Rows.Add(r["c1"].ToString() + " " + r["c2"].ToString(), r["c3"]);
                    }
```

Thank you for your answers...

Edit: I need the answer with C# code, not sql.

Comment: Why you have two for loops? Why not set the DataSource property of the GridView to the DataTable?

Comment: I just started this. That's the method I know.

Comment: Can you please be specific? I guess you mean to ask "avoid duplicate entries in Column1"? Question: don't you want to add up Column2 values for duplicates in COlumn1?

Comment: So you problem is related to what happens in the inside the 2nd loop with the SQL query? I see two ways forward: (a) reformulate the SQL query so that it only returns unique results (and maybe sums up Column2) or (b) write 2 loops: the first collects the data and keeps a hash/directory/map/set of keys to detect already seen keys and the second one generates the datagridview from the unique results.

Comment: could you please show where this `s` comes from? in your for loop => `for (int m1 = 0; m1 < s.Length; m1++)`

Comment: Sir i edited the question. "Hello friends"'s value was a typo.

Comment: @er-mfahhgk s coming from my listbox items.

Comment: @heymycoder, I added my answer, just use `DISTINCT` keyword in your query.

Comment: @er-mfahhgk it doesn't work.

Comment: @heymycoder why you are using two loop? It is not clear what you are trying to do. Can you explain the logic with some example data of `s` array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to avoid duplicate records being displayed in data grid view so why not to select only those distinct records while querying your data.

```
string q = "SELECT DISTINCT c1, c2, c3 FROM mytable......";
```

And rather that iterating over each of row in datatable, you can simply use `DataSource` property of `DataTable` like,

```
SqlDataAdapter s = new SqlDataAdapter(q, c);
DataTable d = new DataTable();
s.Fill(d);
dgw.DataSource = dt;
```

**Edit1:**

You can check the row before adding it to data grid view like

```
foreach (DataRow r in d.Rows)
{
    bool existingRow = dgw.Rows
                          .Cast<DataGridViewRow>().AsEnumerable()
                          .Any(x =>
                                Convert.ToString(x.Cells["Column1"].Value).Split(' ')[0] == r["c1"].ToString() &&
                                Convert.ToString(x.Cells["Column1"].Value).Split(' ')[1] == r["c2"].ToString() &&
                                Convert.ToInt32(x.Cells["Column2"].Value) == Convert.ToInt32(r["c3"])
                           );

     if (!existingRow)
         dgw.Rows.Add(r["c1"].ToString() + " " + r["c2"].ToString(), r["c3"]);
}
```

**Where:**

- `Column1` and `Column2` are the columns in data grid view.
- `c1`, `c2` and `c3` are the columns in data table

Comment: Sir, problem is not in my sql data. They aren't duplicate in my sql table. When I adding them to datagridview, they become duplicate. How can I fix it after "dgw.DataSource = dt;" this code?

Comment: so let me know you have to check only one column or all of three column to prevent duplication?

Comment: All the columns.

Comment: let me know there are only two words that separated with space in your dgv column like `hello friends` is `hello`, `space`, `friends` or may be more than two words?

Comment: Normally they are seperated "hello" and "friends". I combine it when I adding them to datagridview. Column 1 in my datagridview always has two combine words. Normally they splited in my array. But I combine them before adding to dgw.

Comment: answer updated view **Edit1** section in answer and let me know :)

Comment: The first edit didn't work, I'm trying your second edit. :) Do I need this "dgw.DataSource = dt;"?

Comment: So what is the meaning of dt? My DataTable's name is d.

Comment: It says that: "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Rows cannot be programmatically added to the datagridview's row collection when the control is data-bound'"

Comment: I'm trying, one sec sir.

Comment: Sir, it works... Thank you so much. Please don't get me wrong. I'm not betten on. I'm new at this job. Thank you again... I will learn its' logical.

Comment: Do u know where can I work to do this
if I want to normalize that values from between 10 - 2000000 to 0-100 with C# code.?

Comment: Because normally I use this code: 

int cols = Convert.ToInt32(row["c3"].ToString());
                        if (firstIte)
                        {
                            maxVal = cols;
                            firstIte = false;
                        }
                        else if (maxVal < cols)
                        {
                            maxVal = cols;
                        }

But it doesn't work for this code.

Comment: If I understand correctly, normalize means you want to fetch 0-100 records?

Comment: Yes. For second column in my datagridview.

Comment: you can use this => `dgw.DataSource = dgw.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().AsEnumerable().Take(100);` but cant sure it works because i can't get your working environment.

Comment: Hmm. Where should I add this line sir? It's not problem. I will research it.

Comment: try to add it after above `foreach`.

Comment: I tried but I don't use DataSource. I will try it after research it, thank you again...

Answer (score 0):

- These rows are not duplicate You must handle it in your SQL select
- What is your scenario ?  If you Group by Column1, what about
  Column2?
- Sum ? Max? Avg? which one ?

Comment: No. They are duplicate in my datagridview as you can see. I can't handle it in my SQL-Server because already they are not duplicate in SQL. That's what happens when adding to the table.

Comment: hello friends - 85 <> hello friends - 150

Comment: Ok, now you edited , you can simply group by these data in SQL select, no problem

Comment: I can't. Because they are not already duplicate in sql table. They are duplicate when I adding it to my datagridview. Because my loops have same words.